# Can I instantiate multiple objects on the same variable?

Tags: c#, class, object

For example:

```
Enemy enemy;
if(enemy == null)
{
    Enemy enemy = new Enemy();
}
```

And the if this enemy is dead, delete the instance somehow and the re-instance it in the same variable declared above.

Edit: I am using this for a dungeon crawler console game, and I want, that after you kill a monster you would get another encounter.

Comment: sure, just  you don't need to redeclare it, just set a new instance. Currently you are redeclaring it inside the if block

Comment: The above will not compile so I am not really sure what you are asking here...

Comment: Sure, you can assign many objects to a single variable, but unless that variable is a collection, that variable can only hold a single object at a time.

Comment: Change `Enemy enemy = new Enemy();` to just `enemy = new Enemy();`.  You can only declare a variable once in the same scope, but you can assign values to it multiple times

Comment: `delete the instance` <= also what does that mean? How do you propose to delete an instance? You mean just (re)assign the pointer to `null`?

Comment: Yes kind of what I was thinking. Making it null and the redeclaring it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but you must understand the difference between the following two lines of code.

This is an example of *assignment*:

```
a = 10;
```

This is an example of variable *declaration* with an initializer.

```
var a = 10;
```

A variable can be assigned as many times as you want, but can only be declared once (within a scope).

So you can definitely do this:

```
var enemy = new Enemy(); //Declaration
enemy = new Enemy();     //Assignment
enemy = null;            //Assignment
enemy = new Enemy();     //Assignment
```

But you can't do this:

```
var enemy = new Enemy(); //Declaration
var enemy = new Enemy();  //Declaration - will not compile
```

Going back to your example, a working version might look like this:

```
class Game
{
    private Enemy enemy = null; //You have to initialize a field before you can check it, even if you're just checking for null

    public Enemy GetEnemy()
    {
        if (enemy == null)
        {
            enemy = new Enemy();  //Here I am only assigning, not declaring
        }
        return enemy;
    }
}
```

The above is not an uncommon pattern, using a backing field as a cache and loading it on a just-in-time basis.

If all you want is lazy loading like this, you might also consider using a [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting of objects in .net is the responsibility of the garbage collector so you don't have to delete them like, say, in C++.

The object is deleted by the garbage collector as soon as there's no (root) reference to it. So if you just reassign the variable, the old object will not be referenced anymore and the garbage collector will take care of it some time later.

If the moment when the object is destroyed important (it holds and must release some important resources) then you have to implement `IDisposable`.

```
Enemy enemy;

// ...

// time to create the enemy
enemy = new Enemy(); // creating the first one

// ... do something with the first enemy

// creating the second one
enemy = new Enemy(); 
// now there's no reference to the first enemy and it will be destroyed

// playing with second enemy

// dropping the second enemy - it's not referenced now, too and 
// will be destroyed
enemy = null;
```